# ¿Cómo podría yo comparar una variable con cada uno de los elementos de una lista?(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a='a,b,c'
i=0
```

Yo quiero que mi programa pueda decirme si `i` está dentro de `a`.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Podrías iterar con un ciclo sobre el iterable con un condicional pero no tiene sentido, para esto se usa el operador de pertenencia  [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations): `if i in a:...` Por cierto `a` es una cadena no una lista en el ejemplo que das, pero es lo  mismo en principio. Aunque `if "10" in "1,710,8"` te daría `True`. La pregunta es algo básica en principio, un poco de más contexto podría ayudar. Te recomiendo mirarte [tour] y [ask] para ir conociendo mejor el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla ツ. Un saludo.

Comment: Discúlpeme pero no lo he entendido, podría usted escribir el código, me haría un gran favor, empezé en python este diciembre y no entiendo mucho, sobre todo si no es escrito en código

Comment: Ese es el código, un condicional `if i in a: print("El elemento está en la lista")`. Esto es simplemente lo que tienes que hacer para comprobar si el valor de `i` está ene el iterable `a`.

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla